# Twilio error when sending an image Invalid media URL(s)

Tags: c#, .net, twilio, twilio-api

I am using Twilio with .NET.
When I send MMS with Twilio, for example [this random image](https://media.revistagq.com/photos/5f45010acb266484bb785c78/master/pass/dragon-ball-z.jpg),
it works fine, but when I send an image with this URL:
`https://localhost:5000/api/Twilio//747aaee5-cff0-4f47-918c-7505ebd19148.png`

Twilio shows me the error of invalid Url media but my Url has the https protocol.
In the future I will change localhost for other domain, will it work?

Answer (score 0):

When Twilio processes your request to send an MMS, Twilio will retrieve the file from the Media URL that you provided. However, Twilio cannot access your localhost network.

For development, you can tunnel your localhost network to the public internet using tools like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/). You'd run a command like this:

```bash
ngrok http https://localhost:5000
```

The output will display the public Forwarding URL created by ngrok. Any HTTP request to this Forwarding URL will be forwarded to your application listening to `https://localhost:5000`. Use this public Forwarding URL with the path to your file, as your Media URL and Twilio should be able to retrieve it and sent it as an MMS.

When you deploy your application to a web server that is publicly accessible, you won't need a tunnel anymore, but can point to the public domain of your web app.

---

Note, if you don't want your images to be publicly accessible, you can [secure  your application by validating the HTTP request originates from Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/webhooks/webhooks-security).

Comment: Also, be careful about the double `//` in your URL

Comment: Does Twilio support password protected PDF file?

Comment: @im_tsm I believe Twilio supports any file, but the password protection would have to be a feature provided by PDF itself, not Twilio.